# How to show error in modal popup or javascript alert on post method in MVC using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to show error in modal popup or javascript alert on post method in MVC using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?  It's not clear what you're asking, what you're trying to do, or what isn't working.

Comment: why you use error message in  success function ?

Comment: A long title is not useful. Why did you remove details that clarify your specific problem in your edits?

Comment: @Azhar: Now the question is even *less* clear.  You're basically asking how to show information on a page.  *Any* tutorial on ASP.NET MVC will show you the basics to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
error: function () {
 //Place your message here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you catch a error from controller you can assign it a ViewBag.error then you can use this your .cshtml

```
if(ViewBag.error!=null){
<script>alert(Viewbag.error.ToString());</script>// you need to put here a string
}
```